# How to remove \r \n \t and extra \ appended for "=" from the HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#

I am using the HttpWebRequest to pass a URL and then subsequently need to save the html returned by the HttpWebResponse. The response returned has a lot of \r, \n and \t and also all the "=" (equals to) are appended with a backslash. I need to remove them so that the tml returned is clean and directly usable.

Code used is:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://noirimdev02:8080/cps/rde/xchg/rimvenezuela/hs.xsl/1351.htm?xsl=pearl_series_landingpage.xsl&catid=0651C91110FA48BEBFD7C05413185395&pid=F6794FC1CB244538BB592A47505062BC&count=2") as HttpWebRequest;
    // Get response               
    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        // Get the response stream   

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

        // Read the whole contents and return as a string   
        result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    result = result.Replace("\n", " ");
    result = result.Replace("\r", " ");
    result = result.Replace("\t", " ");
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Nimish

Comment: sorry, but I didn't get the question in what isnt working in your example?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe using requests to different URL's. Are you sure that the "problem" isn't in the original HTML string sent by the web server?

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you already handled the \n, \r and \t cases, leaving the trailing '\' after equal signs left to solve, if I understand correctly? You can do that using the same approach as the others:

```
result = result.Replace(@"=\", "=");
```

Or, if you want to handle all the cases at the same time:

```
result = Regex.Replace(result, "[\n\r\t]|=\\\\", delegate(Match match)
{
    return match.Value == @"=\" ? "=" : " ";
});
```